# How to convert large queryset into dataframes in optimized way?

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe

A django queryset of more than 500,000 records when converting into dataframes is getting into OutOfMemory issue.

query_data is returning around 600,000 rows but pandas is unable to process this much data and got stuck. How can we optimize or prevent this.

```
query_data = MyObjects.objects.filter().values()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query_data)
```

Comment: o you need all these items at the same time? While there are techniques to reduce the memory (a bit), if the data is just too much, eventually one runs out of memory, even if it is stored very efficiently.

Comment: Please use numbers or universal measurements instead of local words. Not everyone is going to understand what a *lakh* is.

Answer (score 0):

Try if it is enough for your case:

```
query_data = MyObjects.objects.all().iterator()
df = pd.DataFrame(query_data)
```

Here 2 different tutorial links where you can find solutions for your problem:

[GUGUWEB](https://www.guguweb.com/2020/03/27/optimize-django-memory-usage/)
and
[Francesco Dallanoce](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/pandas-profiling-full-guide-on-complete-data-exploration-in-one-line-of-code-e4c0b023dd2d)

My personal web page for Django subjects
[www.managepy.it](https://www.managepy.it/)